# Launcher Activity's onStart() called before PendingIntent destination activity launched when Application is in Background State

Tags: android, android-activity, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-lifecycle

I am showing notification when FCM message received in `onMessageReceived`. I am launching a intermediate UI less activity (`PushTracker` activity) to do preprocessing of the notification before navigating to destination activity.

I have MainActivity as default launcher activity.

**Problem:**
When app is in foreground/killed state, and notification from FCM is clicked, **PushTracker** is getting called first before anything. Here I will do preprocessing and will navigate to destination screen.

When app goes to background(On pressing home button), and when FCM notification is clicked, First App's Default Launcher Activity(`onStart()`) is getting called. Then after this only , `oncreate()` of PushTracker Activity configured in PendingIntent.

> Important thing here, it is happening only in Android 11 and below. In
> Andorid 12 and above, PushTracker activity is always called first as
> expected.

**One WorkAround:**
If I made MainActivity launch mode as `singleInstance` in AndroidManifest, in Android 11 and below it calls PushTracker first as expected. But in my case I cannot make this change.

I need to figure out why Launcher Activity's `onStart()` is getting called.

I am using **Data Payload** in FCM and handle Navigation myself. Not using notification payload.
Couldn't get much information about this issue.

In App Foreground / Killed state , `PushTracker` is called first before anything on PushClick in all android versions. So its having issue only in App Background state and that too in Android 11 and below.

Any leads / solution will be much appreciated.

**Additional Context:**
The exact reason to fix is, I am using `ApplicationLifecycleObserver`. I need to check whether application is in Foreground/Background in PushTracker and do processing based on it.
Since `LauncherActvity's` `onStart()` is getting called, the `ApplicationLifecycleObserver` onStart() and becomes foreground even when app is in background. In PushTracker application_foreground is always true in this case in Android 11 an below.
But when app is background in Andorid 12 and above, and `PushTracker` is launched first, application_foreground is false in that time as expected. (This is my expectation in other case also)

**Notification:**

```
    private fun sendNotification(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Message:$remoteMessage")
    val notification = remoteMessage.notification
    val requestID = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt()
    val intent = Intent(this,PushTracker::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("remoteMessage",Gson().toJson(remoteMessage))
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVTIY_NEW_TASK
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    val defaultSoundUri: Uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    val notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder =
        NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_1)
            .setLargeIcon(
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    resources,
                    android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_alarm
                )
            )
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_lock)
            .setContentTitle(notification?.title ?: "DEFAULT BODY")
            .setContentText(notification?.body ?: "DEFAULT TITLE")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as? NotificationManager
    notificationManager?.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main)
    Log.d(TAG,"onStart()");
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    Log.d(TAG,"onStart()");
}
}
```

**MainActivity Manifest:**

```
    <activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**PushLanding Activity:**

```
public class PushTracker : FragmentActivity() {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //UI Less Activity for Notification Processing and redirection to destination will be handled here
}
}
```

**PushTracker Manifest:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".PushTracker"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to solve this by making PushTracker activity as singleInstance in Manifest.

**Result:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".PushTracker"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

**Root Cause:**
For standard and other launch modes, on clicking on notification,Pending intent is always routing to destination activity through launcher activity in Android 11 and below. So `onStart()` of Launcher Activity is getting called first.

If we make destination activity as singleInstance,  it will work independently work and so pending intent will not call Launcher Activity's `onStart()`